# How to make Sorting and Filtering working for viewmodel column in InLine editing of Kendo UI MVC grid signalR?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sorting, kendo-ui, signalr, kendo-grid

Sorting and Filtering are not working on the column bound with ViewModel entity. It is working fine with other columns.

Sample Grid Code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<abc.Models.ShippingViewModel>()
    .Name("ShippingGrid")
    .Columns(c =>
    {
        c.Bound(m => m.Id).Hidden();
        c.Bound(m => m.LocationViewModel)
            .ClientTemplate("#=LocationViewModel.LocationName#")
            .Title("Pickup Location")
            .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @title = "Pickup Loactions" });
        c.Bound(m => m.UnitsShipped)
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:right" })
            .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { title = "Units Shipped", style = "text-align: right" });
```

Model:

```
public class InHouseShippingViewModel
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [UIHint("ShippingLocationEditor")]
        public LocationViewModel LocationViewModel { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Units Shipped")]
        [UIHint("ComanexIntegerEditor")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = GlobalVaribleDeclarations.displayFormatForInteger)]
        public int UnitsShipped { get; set; }
    }
```

Hub/Controller code:

```
public IEnumerable<ShippingViewModel> Shipping_Read()
        {
            var queryResult = ShippingRepository.Shipping_Read();
            return queryResult;
        }
```

Here Sorting is working fine on "UnitShipped" column whereas it is not working on "LocationViewModel" column. If I use c.Bound(m => m.LocationViewModel.LocationName), sorting & filtering are working fine but then I am not able to get the DropDownEditor for the this column when editing a record. I am using "InLine" editing here.

I have tested this with "PopUp" editing and everything working fine. I would like to achieve this with "InLine" editing though.

Please advise what should I do to achieve "InLine" editing with Cascading dropdown and Sorting all together. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a mix of things to do. First for filtering etc you need to use the datasourcerequest parameter as in normal ajax calls but then you will find out that sorting does not work.

```
public DataSourceResult Read(MyDataSourceRequest request)
    {
}
```

this does not work since the kendo regular use 'sorts' for passing a collection of sort and this collection is passed by the signalr datasource as 'sort' (no s). you will have to use the dynamic linq nuget package which has a custom datasource request that will work with signalr. Please copy their code in your solution for the custom datarequest object and the slightly todatasourceresult syntax.

http://www.telerik.com/forums/problems-with-grid-using-signalr-and-serverfiltering-sorting-and-paging

relaying information needs a wrap in datasourceresult as well

```
Clients.Others.update(WrapInDataSourceResult(item));

        public DataSourceResult WrapInDataSourceResult(EmployeeViewModel item)
    {
        return new DataSourceResult
               {
                   Data = new[]
                          {
                              item
                          }
               };
    }
```

also you need to activate server side options serverpaging(true) etc

```
.SignalR()
.AutoSync(true)
.Sort(c => c.Add(e => e.FullName).Ascending())
.ServerAggregates(true)
.ServerPaging(true)
.ServerSorting(true)
.ServerGrouping(true)
```

and in the schema

```
 .Schema(schema => schema
    .Data("Data")
    .Total("Total")
    .Aggregates("Aggregates")
    .Groups("Groups")
    .Model(model =>
    {
        model.Id(m => m.EmployeeId);
    })
```